# Launch spring boot in Intellij IDE in bash environment

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-batch

I have a java program which runs a Linux command. When I run it from Intellij using "run as a spring boot app" it fails. As I am running it on windows.

If a run a jar file in Git bash like "Java -jar file.jar" it works.
is there any way to do this within Intellij?

**Code:**

```
        SystemCommandTasklet systemCommandTasklet = new SystemCommandTasklet();
        String Commmand= String.format("tail -1 %s > input_footer.txt", fileName.getFilename());
        logger.info("Commmand  {}",Commmand);
        systemCommandTasklet.setCommand(Commmand);
```

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA has no option to run Java apps in the terminal shell environment at the moment and the Run configuration uses the console implementation which is not a real terminal.

You could try using an external tool if you need to run it from the IDE and configure the app to the shell and `java -jar ...` as the parameters.